# jQuery popup message for newsletter registration

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

the site that this is about is: http://styleriot.net (it's wordpress)
i am familiar with html and php but never did anything in javascript which is the reason why i am writing here.

So what i am trying to build is a jquery popup-message/modal in the head of the site which opens onClick on a link (it's the little mail-icon in the upper right corner of the site). I want it to display a form which allows users to sign up for the newsletter (i am using a plugin for this, so that won't be the problem)

i found a nice thing called messi which i wanted to use. so i did the following in the page  after uploading the files to the server:

```
<!-- messi jquery modal -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./js/messi/messi.css" />
<script src="./js/messi/messi.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function loadMessi() {
    new Messi.load('[wysija_form id="2"]', {title: 'Newsletter abonnieren', modal: true});
  }
</script>
<!-- end messi jquery modal -->
```

(I don't know if the shortcode works here, but that's not the point for now)

The Button/icon itself is like this:

```
<a href="#" onClick="loadMessi()" title="Newsletter abonnieren">
   <img src="http://styleriot.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/email.png" alt="Newsletter" width="25px" height="25px">
</a>
```

The result of this, as you can see, is nothing. The modal doesn't show up.
jQuery is loaded automatically by wordpress, i have other jQuery functions (e.g. lightbox) implemented which work, so i think that won't be the problem.
Thank you for your help

Comment: 1. download Chrome. 2. load page into Chrome. 3. Hit F12. 4. See the 404s in the console: GET http://styleriot.net/js/messi/messi.css 404 (Not Found) (index):145
GET http://styleriot.net/js/messi/messi.js 404 (Not Found)

Comment: The Chrome console returns "Uncaught ReferenceError: Messi is not defined". Like @mplungjan messi.js not loaded properly.